# Is there a way to retrieve the current foreground application in Flutter (while app is running in background)?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am looking to have my Android (Flutter) application running in the background, checking what app is currently running in the foreground.

When a certain app is opened (eg: Snapchat), I would like to redirect the user BACK to my application.

I've seen native android code that can accomplish this, but I was wondering if there were any Flutter-specific plugins that can accomplish this goal?

I'm aware that you can grab a list of currently installed applications using Flutter, but is there a way to see which app is running in the foreground and then redirect back to my own application, or is this something that would have to be done natively?

Comment: "I've seen native android code that can accomplish this" -- not on modern versions of Android.

Comment: Ah shoot, really?  So there is no way to redirect from the foreground application back to your own application?  Any idea how apps like this work? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.mobilesoft.appblock&hl=en_US

Comment: "Any idea how apps like this work?" -- through exploiting some security flaw, presumably. "So there is no way to redirect from the foreground application back to your own application?" -- tens of millions of people will use multi-window (Chrome OS devices, Samsung DeX and equivalents, split-screen mode, etc.). There is no single "foreground application". That, plus the privacy/security issues involved in monitoring what apps are running, are why Google has limited the APIs in this area.